# Win Azure PUT file upload

Tags: flexbuilder, azure-blob-storage, put

I need to upload a file to Win Azure from Flex using PUT method.

In flex I can use URLRequest to upload the file but I don't know what is the URL of the Azure Serveces to file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Azure blobs go to:
http(s)://{storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}/{blobname}